# Class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver not found

Tags: python, jdbc, hive, jaydebeapi

I am trying to access hive from my local machine using hivejdbc driver. but i am facing issues. i am using below code.

not sure how to add jar to python.

```
import jaydebeapi

url = ("jdbc:hive2://" + "<hostname>" + ":" + str(10000)
+ "/"+ "db" +";principal=" + "hive/example.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM." + ";")
conn=jaydebeapi.connect("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", url,<path of jar file>)
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("select * from table limit 10")
curs.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include a library in your project (JAR file) which includes that missing class `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`.

Comment: i am not sure how to add a jar file to python code. Since it is not a java code.

Comment: go through this : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyjnius-dev/OYako-lT59c